# IQueryable and model binding magic?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was testing the new ASP.NET 4.5 model binding for Web Forms, with a simple repository exposing an IQueryable. The repository is using EF 5, Database First approach. I'm projecting the EF auto-generated entity to use my DTO.

Everything works fine, and that's the point, I was expecting to see some kind of exception...

This is the code:

#### Repository

```
    public IQueryable<JobDto> GetJobs()
    {
        var ctx = this.contextResolver.GetCurrentContext<pubsEntities>();

        return ctx.jobs.Select(x => new JobDto
            {
                Description = x.job_desc,
                ID = x.job_id,
                Maximum = x.max_lvl,
                Minimum = x.min_lvl
            });
    }
```

As you can see I'm projecting my EF entity into a custom DTO and the properties are totally different.

#### ASPX Code behind

```
    public IQueryable<JobDto> gv_GetData()
    {
        return this.jobsRepository.GetJobs();
    }
```

#### ASPX

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        SelectMethod="gv_GetData"
        ItemType="QueryRepository.JobDto, QueryRepository">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="My custom description" SortExpression="Description" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This works like a charm, paging and sorting *out of the box* when using a repository which is great (Now I do not have to use an `ObjectDataSource` to simplify things like paging and sorting)

**My question is:**

If my repository is returning `IQueryable<JobDto>` and the properties of my DTO do not have the same name than the properties of my EF entity (which is a different entity named: `job`).

How is it possible that EF can sort my `GridView` correctly since my `GridView` is configured with the property names defined in my DTO entity??? As far as I know, the dynamic sorting using LINQ is done using a string to set the order criteria. Somehow LINQ to Entities - `IQueryable` is auto-mapping my DTO properties to the properties exposed by my EF entity.

Can anyone help this poor soul =( to understand what's happening behind the scenes??

I ran a SQL profile just to confirm that the query is being executed correctly in the database:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[job_desc] AS [job_desc], 
[Project1].[job_id] AS [job_id], 
[Project1].[max_lvl] AS [max_lvl], 
[Project1].[min_lvl] AS [min_lvl]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[job_id] AS [job_id], [Project1].[job_desc] AS [job_desc], [Project1].[min_lvl] AS [min_lvl], [Project1].[max_lvl] AS [max_lvl], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[job_desc] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[job_id] AS [job_id], 
        [Extent1].[job_desc] AS [job_desc], 
        [Extent1].[min_lvl] AS [min_lvl], 
        [Extent1].[max_lvl] AS [max_lvl], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[jobs] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[job_desc] DESC
```

**Pay special attention to these lines (ASPX):**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
```

**And the resulting SQL**

```
ORDER BY [Project1].[job_desc] DESC
```

Comment: Could it be that the IQueryable understands the mapping between `Description` and `job_desc`? This would make sense, otherwise it would be necessary to retrieve and project *all* entities so that the GridView could then sort them.

Comment: Can you confirm that sorting works for ALL your projected dto properties or its just the first (default) one?

Comment: Confirmed. It works for all fields, including the auto-generated fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question lies with how IQueryable operators work. As LINQ queries are executed in deferred mode, the result is not obtained as soon as the method GetJobs is called.

To enable sorting on the ASP.NET GridView, we set the property SortExpression to the column. When we click on the column to sort the data, a dynamic lambda expression is created and the OredrBy operator of is invoked on the result obtained from the SelectMethod of the GridView. We may say that, a statement of following pattern is invoked when we apply sorting :

```
gv_GetData().OrderBy(j => j.Description);
```

Execution of the operator is dependent on the type returned by GetJobs() method. Stepping another level down, we can say that the data returned to the GridView is result of:

```
this.jobsRepository.GetJobs().OrderBy(j => j.Description);
```

Stepping anothet level down, we may assume that, the final LINQ query that will be evaluated is:

```
ctx.jobs.Select(x => new JobDto
        {
            Description = x.job_desc,
            ID = x.job_id,
            Maximum = x.max_lvl,
            Minimum = x.min_lvl
        }).OrderBy(j => j.Description);
```

The SQL query will be formed after parsing all the expressions. Here, we have 2 expressions to parse : one passed to the Select operator and the other passed to the OrderBy operator. Data obtained after parsing both the expressions is used to form the SQL Query.

If we use a method returning IEnumerable as SelectMethod, we get an exception. Because, IEnumerable operators accept Func, which cannot be formed dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

With this code:

```
return ctx.jobs.Select(x => new JobDto
    {
        Description = x.job_desc,
        ID = x.job_id,
        Maximum = x.max_lvl,
        Minimum = x.min_lvl
    });
```

The `Select` overload you're calling is actually creating a new `IQueryable` that affects the actual SQL emitted by EF. You're not really yet projecting the data objects to your DTO's, but rather giving EF an expression it can use to create a query for a result set that is later projected into your DTOs once the query runs. Notice that in the `Select` overload that's being called, an `Expression<Func<Job, JobDto>>` is being passed, not just a `Func<Job, JobDto>`. Because EF analyzes expressions, it is able to do the sophisticated translations to SQL when possible.

When the `OrderBy` expression is added by your `GridView`, it also is just modifying your `IQueryable` with a new expression that can be translated to SQL.

**Edit**:

When you call `Select` on the `IQueryable<Job> jobs` property of your context, EF is able to look at your `Expression<Job, JobDto>` and determine:

1. Which columns are needed from your `JobDto` projection
2. How the `JobDto` projection is populated from the `Job` table.

If you take a look at the many `Expression` classes in the BCL, you'll see how it can go about this. The compiler, when encountering `x => new JobDto { Description = x.job_desc, ... }`, creates a complex expression tree that looks something like this (I'm severely simplifying this):

```
LambdaExpression<Func<Job, JobDto>>
    MemberInitExpression
        NewExpression
        Bindings
            MemberAssignment
                Member = Description property
                Expression = MemberExpression representing access to the Job property
            MemberAssignment...
            MemberAssignment...
            MemberAssignment...
            etc.
```

You can see how this tree contains enough information for EF to walk through the expression and produce internal mappings and produce an equivalent SQL command. They're basically projecting a .NET expression to a SQL expression. Not everything has a 1:1 mapping, but in your case, you can see how straightforward the mapping is:

```
Job type          -> Extent1 alias   -> dbo.jobs table
JobDto projection -> Project1 alias  -> subquery
```

There are other projections, you'll notice; it's introducing a row number property and some mysterious property containing the value `1`; I'm unsure what that's used for.

The `OrderBy` is then an additional augmentation where an `Expression` is analyzed.

Comment: I was thinking something like that. Could you provide more details about the process that is executed behind the scenes so I can fully understand this behavior??. I'm aware that when using `IQueryable` the execution will be referred until the enumerable is actually iterated. I'd like to understand what's happening in the select method that it can emit the correct SQL. For me, it seems like a _map_ is created between both entities

Answer (score 1):

I think it's entirely possible that EF knows how to generate the query since the IQueryable probably hasn't queried for anything until the sorting is applied. I'm thinking you would get the same sql output if you were to run this:

```
var ctx = this.contextResolver.GetCurrentContext<pubsEntities>();

var jobs = ctx.jobs.Select(x => new JobDto
    {
        Description = x.job_desc,
        ID = x.job_id,
        Maximum = x.max_lvl,
        Minimum = x.min_lvl
    }).OrderBy(x => x.Description).ToArray();
```

Edit: Keeping my answer for posterity, but Jacob's is much better written.